# CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs): TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am new to Python and tried following code:

```
import mysql.connector

class DoSomething():
    mysql_param = {...}
    mysqldb = MySqlDB(mysql_param)
    mysqldb.connect()

class MySqlDB():
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.db = mysql.connector.connect(self.mysql_param)

    def __init__(self, mysql_param):
        self.mysql_param = mysql_param
```

Which caused following error:

```
return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I already tried a lot and checked many sources on the internet. Unfortunately I was not able to figure out a solution so far. Any hint is very welcome - big thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself:

```
class MySqlDB():
    def connect(self):
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(**self.mysql_param)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the syntax has changed as they released new version PyMySQL==1.0.2. I have stumbled upon very similar problem with multiple parameters as an input for connect function. The possible solution might be also to downgrade PyMySQL (in my case to 0.9.3)

```
pip uninstall pymysql
pip install pymysql==0.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
class MySqlDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=mysql_host,
            port=mysql_port,
            user=mysql_user,
            password=mysql_pass,
            db=mysql_db
        )
```